# Pyrocms admin page is not work in all browsers when site added in development server

Tags: pyrocms

i have creating a website with pyrocms.
i have seen that the admin page works fine in my localhost in all browsers.
But when i add the site in the development server, the admin page works only in firefox and opera. It did not work in IE and Chrome.
I am using pyrocms 1.3.x version.
i have cleared the browser cache as well as pyrocms cache and try but not working.
I found that it is the problem of session losing after login.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: This was puzzling me for a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved this by myself,

i just edit the config file in `system/cms/config/config.php`

and remove the value of `$config['cookie_domain']`.

ie,

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
```

Hope this may help someone.