# Pyro CMS Admin Panel issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, codeigniter, pyrocms

I am trying to login the following link:

http://localhost/sitename/admin/

the login works fine in IE and other browsers.

But the issue is if we change the URL http://intranetname/sitename/admin/ (intranet name is the internal portal name) then on IE it won't let me login and just refresh the page. Login works fine on Firefox and other browsers.

In IE if i enter wrong user password it says "Invalid Details" but giving the correct details it just refreshes the login page.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This won't be pretty. xD

Comment: Problem solved. Got the answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238358/pyrocms-admin-page-is-not-work-in-all-browsers-when-site-added-in-development-se

Answer (score 2):

`$config['cookie_domain'] = '';`

Set this to be the case if using a netbios name and as the domain is not set for the cookies (ie. accepts them no problem config.php).

Answer (score 0):

IE will expect a valid TLD, and that has to have at least one "." in it. localhost is except from this rule.

When developing locally I always set it as local.foo, or dev.whatever, but no space = problem.